# Doubts on the definition of isolated singularity in Stein and Shakarchi

Tags: complex-analysis

In most literatures, a function $f(z)$ is said to have an isolated singularity at $z_0$ if $f$ is analytic in a deleted neighborhood of $z_0$ but not at $z_0$.

In Stein and Shakarchi,

> By definition, a point singularity of a function $f$ is a complex
> number $z_0$ such that $f$ is defined in a neighborhood of $z_0$ but
> not at the point $z_0$ ifself. We shall also call such points isolated
> singularities.

Obviously two definitions are not equivalent. Can somebody clarify why Stein defined isolated singularities such a way?

Comment: It seems to me that Stein is omitting the analyticity condition only because in the context of complex analysis we generally talk about functions $f(z)$ that are analytic except at its singularities.

Comment: also, the notion of isolated singularity makes sense for continuous functions too, and while less useful than in the analytic case, there are still important cases (harmonic for example) where many things can be said about the function in this case (eg harmonic functions can have isolated logarithmic singularities, in addition to the ones coming from the analytic case, but that's it)

Comment: @Conrad What do you mean by "makes sense for continuous functions"? Do you mean isolated singularity defined in the sense of continuity, not analyticality? So discontinuous point=isolated point?

Comment: the idea is that if a function is continuous and non-zero on a punctured disc, one can define a multiplicity at the singular point which is the usual one in the analytic case; most applications are for harmonic functions and for example lead to important result about zeroes of harmonic polynomials; other applications are analogues of Rouche for continuous functions, Brower theorem etc